# FullCalendar updateEvent is not working : Cannot read property 'clone' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-scheduler

I am using chrome, Fullcalendar 3.4.0 and tried jQuery 1.11.0, 2.2.4, 3.2.1. I am trying just like this, but it is not working. Please help me.

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({});

$('#calendar').fullCalendar('updateEvent', {
  title: 'dddd', 
  start: '2017-07-16'
});
```

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'clone' of undefined

Answer (score 1):

As is mentioned in the documentation: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/updateEvent/

> `event` must be the original Event Object for an event, **not** merely a reconstructed object. The original Event Object can obtained by callbacks such as eventClick, or by the clientEvents method.

You appear to be passing it an arbitrary object that you've just created from nothing. FullCalendar cannot match it to an existing event on the calendar in order to update that event.

It's hard to know since you provided so little context for your question, but if you are trying to create a *new* event on the calendar, then the correct method to use is renderEvent: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_rendering/renderEvent/

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like that .

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    eventClick: function(event, element) {
        event.title = "CLICKED!";
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('updateEvent', event);
    }
});
```

Comment: umm... What is different?

I don't have a event button, and the method 'updateEvent' is not working.

Comment: Just when page load.

Answer (score 0):

Just started using this too, and it appears that both method "updateEvent" and "updateEvents" should be called when you intend to update the existing item / array of events.
If you are adding new events (one by one or in bulk), try "renderEvent" and "renderEvents".

The issue I'm seeing, however, is that those events appear not to persist when you navigate away from e.g. given month and then back.

Comment: "both method "updateEvent" and "updateEvents" should be called". No, you only ever need to call one of them. The first is to update a single event, the second, as should be obvious from the name, is to update a whole set of events. If you're having to do that to make it work, you're doing something wrong.